# C# Singleton with nested class Function and structure

Tags: c#, function, class, nested, singleton

Using singleton lazy as I tried to do is more difficult than I thought.
But I think I've done it at 50%. My question is about the next code, why do I need to pass by the Instanciation _I to reach the 'int function' and not to pass by _I to reach the struct??
Is the singleton right implemented or didn't I understand something??
Thanks

code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Example_Singleton.Singleton.Data.Act_Number + "\n");
       Console.WriteLine(Example_Singleton.Singleton.Time.TLength_Form.Time50ms.ToString()+"\n");
       Example_Singleton.Singleton.Time._IT.waitTimer(3000);  
       Console.WriteLine("done");
       Console.ReadKey();   
    }
}
   class Example_Singleton
{
    public sealed class Singleton
    {
        private Singleton()
        {
        }//ctor singleton
        public static Singleton _I { get { return Nested.instance; } }//instance called for singleton
        private class Nested
        {
            // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
            // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
            static Nested() { }//ctor nested
            internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
        }
        public struct Data
        {//base structure for data station
            public static Int16 Act_Number = 352;
        }
        public sealed class Time/* Class Time for PSX*/
        {
            private Time()
            {
            }//ctor
            public static Time _IT { get { return thisTime.instance; } }
            private class thisTime
            {
                static thisTime() { }//ctor
                internal static readonly Time instance = new Time();
            }
            internal void waitTimer(Int32 TimeLength) //Wait timer
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeLength);
            }
            internal struct User_Time
            {
                public const int RefreshData = 100;
                public const int WaitSynchro = 10;
            }
            internal struct TLength_System    //time length definitions for system time
            {
                public const double Time10ms = 10;
                public const double Time50ms = 50;
            }
            internal struct TLength_Form      //time length definitions for Form time
            {
                public const int Time10ms = 10;
                public const int Time50ms = 50;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do with this singleton pattern ? It seems you built up something very complex, which you may not need.

Comment: I'd like to have only one instance of a bunch of used nested class which a lot of Formclass are using. Like Time, we don'T need a lot of tomer instance. Or then I would add a server class singleton where only one instance method Read and write can be intanciated, so I'm sure that only one caller access to the server at one time... that's the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed the `Time`class to the following

```
    public sealed class Time/* Class Time for PSX*/
    {
        private Time()
        {
        }//ctor
        private static object _oLock = new object();
        private static Time _it;
        public static Time _IT 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                if(_it == null)
                    lock(_oLock)
                        if (_it == null)
                            _it = new Time();

                return _it;
            }
        }
        internal void waitTimer(Int32 TimeLength) //Wait timer
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeLength);
        }
        internal struct User_Time
        {
            public const int RefreshData = 100;
            public const int WaitSynchro = 10;
        }
        internal struct TLength_System    //time length definitions for system time
        {
            public const double Time10ms = 10;
            public const double Time50ms = 50;
        }
        internal struct TLength_Form      //time length definitions for Form time
        {
            public const int Time10ms = 10;
            public const int Time50ms = 50;
        }
    }
```

You would only have to use the singleton like this

```
Time._IT.waitTimer(3000);
```

Notice the lock object allowing your singleton to be thread safe.